# Can not get public key from .cer files using openssl on C

Tags: c, openssl

Using openssl in code `EVP_PKEY *d2i_PUBKEY_fp(FILE *fp, EVP_PKEY **a)` method can not get public key in .cer file.

```c
int load_cert() {

    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/android/cafile/cerfile.cer", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open: %s\n", path);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    X509 *x509data = NULL;
    // X509 *cert = d2i_X509_bio(fp, NULL);
    d2i_X509_fp(fp, &x509data);
    if (!x509data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to parse certificate in: %s\n", path);
        fclose(fp);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char issuer_name[1024];
    char subject_name[1024];

    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(x509data), issuer_name,
                      sizeof(issuer_name));
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(x509data), subject_name,
                      sizeof(subject_name));

    printf("Issuer  name: %s\n", issuer_name);
    printf("Subject name: %s\n", subject_name);

    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    EVP_PKEY *a = NULL;
    //d2i_PUBKEY_fp(fp, &a);
    pkey = d2i_PUBKEY_fp(fp, &a);
    d2i_PUBKEY_fp(fp, NULL);
    if (pkey == NULL) {
        printf("d2i_PUBKEY_fp pkey error\n");
    }
    if (a == NULL) {
        printf("d2i_PUBKEY_fp a error\n");
    }
// any additional processing would go here..
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

[cerfile.cer file](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/files/3197132/cerfile.cer.zip)

`issuer_name` and `subject_name` can be obtained correctly, but `pkey` and `a` are null.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be expecting the public key to be in a serialized form directly after the X509 certificate in the file. The public key is contained *within* the certificate - so you already read it when you did the `d2i_X509_fp` call and it is contained within the `x509data` object. To extract it out as an EVP_PKEY use `X509_get_pubkey` as documented here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_get_pubkey.html

Comment: I use 
 ```
EVP_PKEY *key = X509_get_pubkey(x509data);
 ```
get  an EVP_PKEY ,and later i use 
 ```
 unsigned char *p = NULL;
    int i = i2d_PUBKEY(key, &p);
int size = sizeof(p);
 ```
 to get a char array ,but the result is always 8 byte ,
but my publickey size is 65 byte ,how this happened ？

Comment: "int size = sizeof(p)" will give you the size of the pointer "p" not the size of the data pointed to by "p". On your platform it seems that pointers are always 8 bytes long. What you need to do is something like "char *p, *tmpp; int size = i2d_PUBKEY(key, NULL); p = tmpp = malloc(size); size = i2d_PUBKEY(key, &tmpp);". Then the size of your encoded data is in size, and it is in the location pointed to by "p". Note that i2d_PUBKEY modifies the pointer passed into it, hence the use of "tmpp" as a temporary pointer.